# Is it possible to accept card payments direct through Virtuemart 3?

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

Using Joomla 2.5 / Virtuemart 3. Our client wants to add direct card payments to the site to avoid PayPal's transactions fees etc. So is it possible to accept card payments without a third party plugin? Can it be done direct on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal Payments Pro allows payments direct on the site in an iframe which we are currently in the process of implementing.